# I have installed tensorflow and tflearn for creating chatbots during importing it shows errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk, tflearn

this was my code

```
# Libraries needed for NLP
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

# Libraries needed for Tensorflow processing
import tensorflow as tf
```

> error!
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
>   in 
>        57 
>   ---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>        59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import **version**
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
>   in 
>        27             return _mod
>   ---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>        29     del swig_import_helper
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py
>   in swig_import_helper()
>        23             try:
>   ---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname,
>   description)
>        25             finally:
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py in
>   load_module(name, file, filename, details)
>       241         else:
>   --> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>       243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py in
>   load_dynamic(name, path, file)
>       341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
>   --> 342         return _load(spec)
>       343
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL)
>   initialization routine failed.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 # Libraries needed for Tensorflow processing
>         2 
>   ----> 3 import tensorflow as tf
>         4 import numpy as np
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py
>   in 
>        22 
>        23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
>   ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>        25 
>        26 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py
>   in 
>        47 import numpy as np
>        48 
>   ---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>        50 
>        51 # Protocol buffers
>
> c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
>   in 
>        72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>        73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
>   ---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
>        75 
>        76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py",
>   line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "c:\users\acuwin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py",
>   line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0`? You should try running this:

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'pip', 'm', 'install', 'tensorflow'])
try:
    import tensorflow
    print('Tensorflow is installed.')
except ImportError:
    print('You have not installed tensorflow.')
```

Comment: Hii thank you it worke but still it shows 'NO module name "tensorflow.contrib"'

Comment: That's a warning that I got to, but mine still worked